# Login like I login in Postman with Basic AUth

Tags: android-studio

In Postman I'm using "Basic Auth" to login to the backend and I get a Jwt. Now I want to make a Login activity in Android Studio, doing the same thing. But How do I set up the REST API? I can't just send the Username/Password values in the Header or Body and how do I extract the JWT from the response?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. In the Header Tab, set the KEY: Authorization and VALUE: Basic name:password (but encoded with Base64). I can replicate this in a Android Studio